# How to add an existing form in a specific tabpage of a main form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm working on an Access database that will generate forms automatically. For each form, I want to add a page with the same name of the form, and this page will contain the form.

For now, I managed to create the forms, to add a page on the tab control but I can't find the way to add the form created into the page.

In design view, it's possible to drag and drop the form directly into the page. Is there any way in VBA code to obtain the same result ?

Update: I want for the forms inserted to have 'Link Master Fields' and 'Link child fields' empty (unbound form).

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by 'generate forms automatically'? Why programmatically building forms? Need a subform container control on the Tab control page. Then set the container SourceObject property.

Comment: It will be used for a data entry database, each protocol will have a form associated. Definitions of protocol are in SQL server, if we generate automatically the forms, if a protocol is updated, no changes will have to be done in the access database.  Could you explain me how to create the subform container control ?

Comment: Have no idea how to do that with code. Not finding a lot of info on programmatically establishing objects with VBA because whole idea behind Access is the application does a lot of the coding for you (drag & drop, wizards, etc). And I still do not understand the need. I have no idea what you mean by 'protocol'. If a protocol is updated, then certainly code has to be modified? Why not just manually do design changes? If you want to manually add empty container control to a tab control, do it the same way as any other control - LinkedMaster/Child and SourceObject properties will not be set.

Comment: If the maximum number of forms and fields is known, just create manually maximum of them, then dynamically you can show/hide tabs, forms, and controls, it's much easier than creating them using VBA. Also, you won't be able to make an executable accde - cannot open the form in design mode in accde.